# show zero values query

Tags: mysql, sql

i want to show even if anyone do not have a value.

```
 SELECT tablesite.name,
        tablesite.family,
        tablesite.phone_number,
        COUNT(*)
        FROM tablesite
        LEFT JOIN action
        ON tablesite.id_user=action.service_provider_id
        WHERE action.vote !='' AND customer_comment =''
        GROUP BY name
```

> the result is this. i want all persons even with zero value.

[image: result]

this is my "tablesite":

[image: tablesite]

and this is table "action":

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then move the 2 conditions from the WHERE clause into the JOIN condition. The rationale is that the where clause is applied when the 2 tables are joined, therefore eliminating those persons, who would have 0 action:

```
SELECT tablesite.name,
        tablesite.family,
        tablesite.phone_number,
        COUNT(action.service_provider_id)
        FROM tablesite
        LEFT JOIN action
        ON tablesite.id_user=action.service_provider_id and action.vote !='' AND action.customer_comment =''
        GROUP BY name, family, phone_number
```

I also extennded the group by clause to make your code sql standard compliant. Your group by version runs only under certain conditions even within mysql.

UPDATE: Forgot to change the basis of the count: count(*) count the rows returned, which will be at least 1 for each person because the record from the tableside table. Change it to count(action.service_provider_id) (this is the column you join the action table on) to count the number of records coming from the action table.

Answer (score 3):

BY putting the predicate in the WHERE clause instead of the JOIN clause you're causing all rows without those values to be excluded.  Moving the predicaties to the join will allow all rows from `tablesite` returned including so that you'll get results that have a count of 0.

The COUNT also needs to be change, to be prefixed by the action table, so you don't include the count of rows returned by tablesite.

```
SELECT tablesite.name,
    tablesite.family,
    tablesite.phone_number,
    COUNT(action.action_id)
    FROM tablesite
    LEFT JOIN action
        ON tablesite.id_user=action.service_provider_id
        AND action.vote !='' AND action.customer_comment =''
    GROUP BY name, family, phone_number
```

Since I didn't know what columns could be null, I just made up an action_id column that I would assume was your primary key and not null.  If you count a column that is nullable it might not be included

Comment: that shows some where value=1 for empty rows! and some where 2! why?

Comment: Fixed.  I should've had count(action.*)

Comment: it does not accept "action.*" but i put "action.vote" or "action.customer_comment" it works. where is the problem with "action.*"?

Comment: I changed my answer accordingly.  You should be careful with action.vote because if it is nullable then the row won't get counted.